# Adding source code from Maven library in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I've been using the Ebay SDK in my Maven project but have run into an issue and now I need to include the Ebay SDK sources in my project so that I can see what's happening inside the library. I've included the source libraries as Maven dependencies but when debugging I can still not step into the library.

Anybody have any thoughts as to what I could do?

JLove

Answer (score 5):

In Netbeans, in Projects window, your project/dependencies node, right clic on the librairy node you want ; you have "Download sources" choice. Do that.

And you can see these sources and go into during debug.

Comment: If you are struggling to do this behind a proxy, in the 'Advanced Proxy Options' unclick 'Use the same proxy settings for all protocols' https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211387

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents, in case you don't know the exact library, but have a class name:

1. First I tried to use Maven plugin (`maven-dependency-plugin`) in the project POM to download the sources, but I think it was not the wise solution in the end, because, first, all sources are downloaded, not just the stuff you want to debug, and second, I am not sure that Netbeans will understand that sources were downloaded anyway - so the below procedure will be necessary in all cases.
2. Just go straight to `Navigate` -> `Go to Type` (`Ctrl + O`) and choose the class you want to debug (unless you don't know the class - but at least you should have an inkling from some kind of a stack trace you had seen before)
3. The class will open but with either stubs or some other kind of generated code. Thankfully, you will see a ribbon right under the `Source`/`History` tabs that will say something like `No sources found. Showing generated code for ...` - and there will be a button to the right that should say `Attach Sources...`. The dialog that will open if you click on that button will have an option to either add an existing folder or to Download. The `Download` action should place the downloaded sources in a `xx-sources.jar` file next to the actual Maven jar, inside the `.m2` folder (at least this happened in my case). When the download completes, there will be something to select in the Attach Sources dialog, and the full code of the class will open. You will be able to set breakpoints there.
4. There is still a chance that while starting the application, the `Debugger Console` will display something like : `Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint SomeDebuggedClass.java : X, reason: The breakpoint is set outside of any class.` I found it useful in general to do the 2 and 3 steps above **while** debugging, so that when I actually set a breakpoint, it is immediately visible if the breakpoint can be set (it will appear as a broken icon if there's something wrong). And in most cases what is wrong is that somehow the code you are trying to debug does not correspond exactly to the code that was found and its sources were downloaded. In my case there is a big chance that there is some mix up in the dependencies and another version of the library got picked up by the classloader.
5. There is also `Window` -> `Debugging` -> `Sources` - with the above procedure, the sources that were downloaded are added to that window automatically - so no need to experiment with that.